# static variables in C structs

Tags: c, struct, static, declaration

When I try to declare a struct with a static variable in it, the code doesn't get compiled and produces the error mentioned below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

struct test {
    int value;
    static int staticValue = 0;
}; 

return 0;
}
```

The error I get is;

```
 expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘static’
  static int staticValue = 0;
  ^
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: `C` doesn't support `static` members

Comment: I had an assignment saying that I should include a static member in a structure.
"Declare a structure (call it test) that has members a one dimensional array of ten integer elements, an enumerated field for days of the week, a float number, and a **static** integer"
@imreal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might *not* want to declare your `struct` inside the `main` function -- that limits its scope to that of the function, which is seldom what you want.

Then, in C, `static` refers to object lifetime, and not to struct members. What you want is a `static` class member, which is a C++ (and *not* a C) construct.

Comment: What's wrong with defining a `struct` inside a function?

Comment: @imreal: It's valid C89/C90, but declaring a data structure (which is what `struct`s are meant for) inside a main function shouts "my developer wanted something else than what was written", namely, a elegant way to keep data together across function boundaries.

Comment: @imreal: better? I've made an edit

Comment: I tried it outside the main as well and still I didn't get any luck  @MarcusMüller

Comment: @rajeerc: You haven't read my full answer. That's not the problem; the problem is that `static`, as you use it, is **not** valid in C.

Comment: What do you mean by "in C, static referes to object lifetime". Does it mean that there is a use of **static** in C? If so, how is it used? @MarcusMüller

Comment: @rajeerc: exactly like I wrote it: it defines when an object starts and stops to exist. Please use your google/wikipedia skills, this is clearly out of scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `static` variable inside a struct. It would needlessly complicate things if all structs of that type had to share one variable.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing (`static` in struct) is only allowed in C++ not C.